# expanding range with COUNTIF and INDIRECT function

Tags: excel, countif

I want reference an expanding range in the COUNTIF function in excel such that the starting reference of the expanding range is identified by an INDEX and MATCH functions combination.

let's say I have the following data in column A: {1;1;0}.

I could use the following COUNTIF formula in cell B1 to count the cumulative number of times the 1s, and 0s appear in the column A data as follows:

in cell B1: COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)

The result of this function, if I were to drag it down from B1:B3 would be:

{1;2;1}

Here's the question:

I can locate the first '1' to appear in column A as cell A1 using the INDEX and MATCH functions.

How can I create the "$A$1:A1" value for the [range] argument and the "A1" value for the [criteria] argument of the COUNTIF function by referencing the 'A1' identified from the INDEX and MATCH function combination so that when I drag it down it will increment the row value as expected whenever we drag a relative cell references down a column?

If this formula were to be entered in cell C1, the resulting values in cells C1:C3 should be {1;2;1}

here's an example of a formula I've tried that produces the following result {1;1;1}. Basically, the row value does not increment as I would like it to:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(CELL("address",INDEX($A$1:$A$3,MATCH(1,$A$1:$A$3,0)))):INDIRECT(LEFT(ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX($A$1:$A$3,MATCH(1,$A$1:$A$3,0))),COLUMN(INDEX($A$1:$A$3,MATCH(1,$A$1:$A$3,0))),4),1)&ROW(INDEX($A$1:$A$3,MATCH(1,$A$1:$A$3,0)))),INDEX($A$1:$A$3,MATCH(1,$A$1:$A$3,0)))
```

Hope some one can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: so you want the formula to find the first `1` and set that as the absolute reference and have the second part continue to be relative to the row in which the formula is placed?

Comment: The row value is never going to increment, because `ROW(INDEX($A$1:$A$3,MATCH(1,$A$1:$A$3,0)))`  is always 1. With your data, `MATCH(1,$A$1:$A$3,0)` always returns 1. The index function with 1 substituted for match is `INDEX($A$1:$A$3,1)`. With your data, that also always returns 1. So, finally you get `ROW(1)`, which is always 1.

Comment: Thanks @StoneGiant for your observation. I agree with you.  Do you know a work-around that might get me what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Scott Craner what you describe sounds correct.  What I presented was a simplification of my actual data. I actually have the first '1' several rows below several 'text' values and so I would need to locate this cell as my starting absolute reference, and then be able to drag down as in the COUNTIF formula I gave as an example: =COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1). Hope this comments add more clarity to what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use index for the first and leave the second as a reference

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1,A:A,0)):A1,A1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I can see the utility of using the INDEX function first, but how can I refer to the 'A1' value without typing it manually. if the first '1' appears at row 27 for example, how could I get excel to refer to A27 without me actually typing 'A27' for the ending reference of the dynamic range, and the value for the [criteria] argument of the COUNTIF function?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain most of your original formula, try

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(CELL("address",INDEX($A$1:$A$3,MATCH($A$1,$A$1:$A$3,0)))):INDIRECT(LEFT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(INDEX($A$1:$A$3,MATCH(A2,$A$1:$A$3,0))),4),1)&ROW()),INDEX($A$1:$A$3,MATCH(A2,$A$1:$A$3,0)))
```

I condense ROW() and modify the first argument of MATCH(), though there seem to be several extra calcs.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I copied the formula you offered into excel in cell C1 and dragged down (C1:C3) and I got the result {1;0;1}.  Seems close, but not entirely what I'm looking for.  The end result should be {1;2;1}.  Thanks for your help, nonetheless.

Comment: Sorry, copied the wrong cell. If you copy the above into cell C2 then copy and paste into C1:C3, it should work. The first argument in the Match() should be A1 when in C1.